# how to show/hide div based on selected option's id?

Tags: javascript, php, html, show

I have this vehicles invoice form with 5 rows. each row can be a different vehicle but if a car is selected, it shows you a second select list to chose its color.

here is my javascript:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#select1").change(function(event) {
            var id = $(event.target).id();

            $("#" + id).show();
        });
    });
</script>
```

here is my form:

```
  <form name="invoice" action="invoice.php">
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>SN</td>
        <td>Vahicle Type</td>
        <td>Quantity</td>
    </tr>


      <?php $sn = 1 ;
       while ($sn < 5){ ?>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <?php echo $sn ?>
        </td>
        <td>
              <select name="vehicles[]" id="select1">
                  <option id="0" value="0">Select Vehicle</option>
                  <option id="<?php echo $sn ?>" value="toyota" name="toyota">Toyota</option>
                  <option id="<?php echo $sn ?>" value="nissan" name="nissan">Nissan</option>
                  <option id="<?php echo $sn ?>" value="BMW" name="bmw">BMW</option>
                  <option id="0" value="plane" name="plane">Plane</option>
                  <option id="0" value="boat" name="boat">Boat</option>
                  <option id="0" value="bike" name="bike">Bike</option>

              </select>    

          <div id="<?php echo $sn ?>" class="toggleable" style="display:none;">
              <select name="color[]" id="select2">
                  <option id="<?php echo $sn ?>" value="red" name="red">Red</option>
                  <option id="<?php echo $sn ?>" value="black" name="black">Black</option>
                  <option id="<?php echo $sn ?>" value="white" name="white">White</option>          
              </select>    
          </div>

        </td>

        <td>
            <input type="number" name="quantity[]">
        </td>
    </tr>

            <?php $sn=$sn+1; } ?>
</table>
</form>
```

im not so good with javascript. i wrote this code by learning from online examples but its not working.

Comment: `event.target` is the `select` element, use its value instead of `id`s of options.

Answer (score 1):

As tomas_b said, you should be using a *data-** attribute for this. Element IDs must be unique within the document, if you duplicate them then *getElementById* will only return the first one (mostly).

If the listener is on the select element, then it will be *this* within the function, its properties can be accessed directly. There is also rarely any need to add an ID to a form control that already has a name, and select elements should always have one option with the selected attribute so that you know one will be selected by default.

So you might do something like:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('select1').onchange = handleVehicleChange;
}

function handleVehicleChange() {
  var opt = this.options(this.selectedIndex);
  document.getElementById('carTypes').style.display = opt.getAttribute('data-type') == 'car'? '' : 'none';
}
```

```html
     <select name="vehicles[]" id="select1">
        <option id="0" value="0" selected>Select Vehicle</option>
        <option data-type="car" value="toyota">Toyota</option>
        <option data-type="car" value="nissan">Nissan</option>
        <option data-type="car" value="BMW">BMW</option>
        <option data-type="aeroplane" value="plane">Plane</option>
        <option data-type="boat" value="boat">Boat</option>
        <option data-type="bike" value="bike">Bike</option>
    </select>    

    <div id="carTypes" class="toggleable" style="display:none;">
      <select name="color[]" id="select2">
        <option value="red">Red</option>
        <option value="black">Black</option>
        <option value="white">White</option>          
      </select>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To obtain the value of the selected option "id" attribute using jQuery, you can use the following jQuery snippet

```
var id = $("#select1 > option:selected").attr('data-id');
```

See it in action: http://plnkr.co/edit/bWj0MzLey0n4dkI03bs1?p=preview

The query here simply gets you the selected option using the ":selected" selector (https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

However as seen in the example, you should use a different attribute name for the option tags, e.g. "data-id", as "id" has its purpose.

Comment: Which is a really inefficient way to do `this.id`. But the OP is (rightly or wrongly) after the ID of the selected option, not the select element that has the listener and hence will the *this* within the function.

Comment: var id = $(this).attr('id'); i did that but still not working. i have to use option's id as there are 5 rows and each row's selection can be different. div's id is based on row's number.

Comment: @RobG - right, I understand the intention of the OP now. Edited my answer.

Comment: @tomas_b  - it works but if it is only one row. it doesn't do anything on row 2, 3, 4, 5.